# Using apache-airflow-providers-snowflake on airflow (no module named Snowflake)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

I have installed package `apache-airflow-providers-snowflake` on airflow on docker and i am getting error

> No module named Snowflake
> Please refer attachment (check the error mentioned for the snowflake hook file)
> [image]
> After analysis i found that the the snowflake hook operator source code is getting saved with file name snowflake.py and within the source code it tries to import snowflake module. So basically it is trying to import itself.

```
import logging

import airflow
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
#from snowflake.connector import *
#import snowflake.connector
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

args = {"owner": "Airflow", "start_date": datetime.datetime.now()}

dag = DAG(
    "snowflake_poc", default_args=args, schedule_interval=None
)

#create_insert_query = [
#    """INSERT INTO STRUCTURED.error_details_log (SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"row_num": "13456"}'),current_date());""",
#]


def row_count(**context):
    dwh_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_conn")
    result = dwh_hook.get_first("select count(*) from STRUCTURED.LKP_GENDER")
    print(result)
    logging.info("Number of rows in `STRUCTURED.LKP_GENDER`  - %s", result[0])


with dag:
    get_count = PythonOperator(task_id="get_count", python_callable=row_count)
get_count
```

```
$ pip freeze
adal==1.2.6
alembic==1.5.5
amqp==2.6.1
apache-airflow @ file:///opt/airflow
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==1.1.0
apispec==3.3.2
appdirs==1.4.4
argcomplete==1.12.2
asn1crypto==1.4.0
attrs==20.3.0
azure-batch==10.0.0
azure-common==1.1.26
azure-core==1.11.0
azure-cosmos==3.2.0
azure-datalake-store==0.0.51
azure-identity==1.5.0
azure-keyvault==4.1.0
azure-keyvault-certificates==4.2.1
azure-keyvault-keys==4.3.1
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.2.0
azure-kusto-data==0.0.45
azure-mgmt-containerinstance==1.5.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.2.2
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg==3.0.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-store==0.5.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-mgmt-resource==15.0.0
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-storage-blob==12.7.1
azure-storage-common==2.1.0
azure-storage-file==2.1.0
Babel==2.9.0
bcrypt==3.2.0
billiard==3.6.3.0
boto3==1.15.18
botocore==1.18.18
cached-property==1.5.2
cachetools==4.2.1
cattrs==1.2.0
celery==4.4.7
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
clickclick==20.10.2
cloudpickle==1.4.1
colorama==0.4.4
colorlog==4.7.2
commonmark==0.9.1
connexion==2.7.0
croniter==0.3.37
cryptography==3.4.6
dask==2021.2.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
dill==0.3.3
distlib==0.3.1
distributed==2.19.0
dnspython==1.16.0
docker==3.7.3
docker-pycreds==0.4.0
docutils==0.16
elasticsearch==7.5.1
elasticsearch-dbapi==0.1.0
elasticsearch-dsl==7.3.0
email-validator==1.1.2
eventlet==0.30.1
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-AppBuilder==3.1.1
Flask-Babel==1.0.0
Flask-Caching==1.9.0
Flask-JWT-Extended==3.25.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-OpenID==1.2.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
flower==0.9.7
gevent==21.1.2
google-ads==7.0.0
google-api-core==1.26.0
google-api-python-client==1.12.8
google-auth==1.27.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.2
google-cloud-automl==2.1.0
google-cloud-bigquery==2.9.0
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==3.0.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.3.0
google-cloud-bigtable==1.7.0
google-cloud-container==1.0.1
google-cloud-core==1.6.0
google-cloud-datacatalog==3.0.0
google-cloud-dataproc==2.2.0
google-cloud-dlp==1.0.0
google-cloud-kms==2.2.0
google-cloud-language==1.3.0
google-cloud-logging==2.2.0
google-cloud-memcache==0.3.0
google-cloud-monitoring==2.0.1
google-cloud-os-login==2.1.0
google-cloud-pubsub==2.3.0
google-cloud-redis==2.0.0
google-cloud-secret-manager==1.0.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.19.1
google-cloud-speech==1.3.2
google-cloud-storage==1.36.0
google-cloud-tasks==2.1.0
google-cloud-texttospeech==1.0.1
google-cloud-translate==1.7.0
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.16.1
google-cloud-vision==1.0.0
google-cloud-workflows==0.2.0
google-crc32c==1.1.2
google-resumable-media==1.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
graphviz==0.16
greenlet==1.0.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.35.0
grpcio-gcp==0.2.2
gunicorn==19.10.0
HeapDict==1.0.1
httplib2==0.19.0
humanize==3.2.0
hvac==0.10.8
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
importlib-resources==1.5.0
inflection==0.5.1
iso8601==0.1.14
isodate==0.6.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jmespath==0.10.0
json-merge-patch==0.2
jsonschema==3.2.0
kombu==4.6.11
kubernetes==11.0.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
ldap3==2.9
libcst==0.3.17
lockfile==0.12.2
Mako==1.1.4
Markdown==3.3.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
marshmallow==3.10.0
marshmallow-enum==1.5.1
marshmallow-oneofschema==2.1.0
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.23.1
msal==1.9.0
msal-extensions==0.3.0
msgpack==1.0.2
msrest==0.6.21
msrestazure==0.6.4
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
mysql-connector-python==8.0.22
mysqlclient==1.3.14
natsort==7.1.1
numpy==1.20.1
oauthlib==2.1.0
openapi-spec-validator==0.2.9
oscrypto==1.2.1
packaging==20.9
pandas==1.2.2
pandas-gbq==0.14.1
paramiko==2.7.2
pendulum==2.1.2
portalocker==1.7.1
prison==0.1.3
prometheus-client==0.8.0
proto-plus==1.13.0
protobuf==3.15.1
psutil==5.8.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pycryptodomex==3.10.1
pydata-google-auth==1.1.0
Pygments==2.8.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
PyNaCl==1.4.0
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent==0.17.3
pysftp==0.2.9
python-daemon==2.3.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-editor==1.0.4
python-http-client==3.3.2
python-ldap==3.3.1
python-nvd3==0.15.0
python-slugify==4.0.1
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2020.5
pytzdata==2020.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
redis==3.5.3
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.1.0
rich==9.2.0
rsa==4.7.1
s3transfer==0.3.4
sendgrid==6.6.0
setproctitle==1.2.2
six==1.15.0
slack-sdk==3.4.0
snowflake-connector-python==2.3.10
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.4
sortedcontainers==2.3.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.23
SQLAlchemy-JSONField==1.0.0
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.36.8
sshtunnel==0.1.5
starkbank-ecdsa==1.1.0
statsd==3.3.0
swagger-ui-bundle==0.0.8
tabulate==0.8.8
tblib==1.7.0
tenacity==6.2.0
termcolor==1.1.0
text-unidecode==1.3
toolz==0.11.1
tornado==6.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
typing-inspect==0.6.0
unicodecsv==0.14.1
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.25.11
vine==1.3.0
virtualenv==20.4.2
watchtower==0.7.3
websocket-client==0.57.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
WTForms==2.3.3
zict==2.0.0
zipp==3.4.0
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.2.0
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Please provide your code & provide information about your configurations.

Comment: @Elad, have attached the screenshot of the error. I haven't yet executed the custom code that i have written. i am getting an error after the installation of snowflake hook from providers package.

Comment: can you please add pip freeze?

Comment: Can you show your dag code?

Comment: @SimonDarr, added the dag code. The SnowflakeHook operator is the one that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Elad, I have the snowflake connector installed, however the issue is with the SnowflakeHook operator.

Comment: Please show pip freeze

Comment: @Elad attached the pip freeze output

Comment: @Vidya821 :  Have you found any workaround?

Comment: you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am importing below library and its working fine for with `airflow 2.0.2` and `snowflake-connector-python==2.4.3`.

```
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator
```